# JSP returning null when I add 'for' loop

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Java Web application, when I try to execute my JSP it returns : 
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

I verified and my Request Attribute it's not null, and it only returns error 500 when I add a For Loop.

Here's my JSP:

```
<%
    Object obj=(Object) request.getAttribute("estados");
    ArrayList <Estado> estadosLista = (ArrayList<Estado>)obj;

    for (int i = 0;i < estadosLista.size();i++) { 
        out.println("<option value = " + i+1 + ">" + estadosLista.get(i).getNome() + "</option>"  );
    }
%>
```

If i remove For() my JSP runs OK.

```
<%
                     Object obj=(Object) request.getAttribute("estados");


                    ArrayList <Estado> estadosLista = (ArrayList<Estado>)obj;





                   }






                   %>
```

And in my Servlet i'm using :

```
 request.setAttribute("estados",estados);            
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("principal.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

PS : My attribute it's not null, since when  I Run directly in my Servlet, the application runs OK , and the for loop works perfectly filling all my select(html) options.

Comment: Your request attribute **is** null; or your `List` is full of null(s). Only possible explanation.

Comment: I checked both, and they're not null, the're filling perfect my <select> options when i execute directly in servlet.

Comment: You shouldn't be using scriptlets in your jsp anyway.

Comment: What about yout object "out"? could you check if it is null?